# Wait for HTMLMediaElement.play() promise's resolution before calling pause()

Tags: javascript, audio, promise, html5-audio, playback

I have kind of situation to call pause() when promise returned by play() yet to resolve. On calling pause() I am getting error `AbortError` from the browser. In my case this error is handled by common errorHandler which in turn showing it up in UI which does not look pleasant to user.

Similar code snipped:

```
errorHandler = function(){} //Error handler showing error in UI.
var audio_el = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("audio")
PlayMedia(newSrc) {
    audio_el.src = newSrc;
    try {
       var playPromise = audio_el.play();
       Promise.resolve(playPromise).catch(errorHandler)
    } catch(err) {
       errorHandler(err);
    }
}

StopMedia() {
   if (audio) {
        audio_el.pause();
        audio_el.currentTime = 0;
   }
}
```

I have to call `StopMedia()` just before calling `PlayMedia()` with same or different src. As `audio_el.pause(`) or `audio_el.src = newSrc` (changing `src` also causes pause trigger internally) is triggered when on going `playPromise` is not resolved due to this browser safari throws error `AbortError: The operation was aborted.`

How can I wait play() promise's resolution before calling pause?? or How can I avoid AbortError?
Is there a way to abort play without throwing exception from browser?

Note: multiple clicking media element causing above two function call.